# Diagonals to rows in data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a matrix-like data frame with an additional column denoting time. It contains information on the number of enrolled students in a given school, from grade 5 (column `A`) to grade 9 (column `E`).

```
  time    A    B    C    D    E
1   13 1842 1844 1689 1776 1716
2   14 1898 1785 1807 1617 1679
3   15 2065 1865 1748 1731 1590
4   16 2215 1994 1811 1708 1703
5   17 2174 2122 1903 1765 1699
```

I need to trace the size of the cohort over time, meaning that I need row-wise information on how many fifth graders from each starting year remained in the school from grades 6 through 9. For example, for the cohort that has begun fifth grade in 2013, I want information on how many remained in sixth grade in 2014, and so on.

**Expected output**

This is what I would like to end up with:

```
  start.time point.A point.B point.C point.D point.E
1         13    1842    1785    1748    1708    1699
2         14    1898    1865    1811    1765      NA
3         15    2065    1811    1765      NA      NA
4         16    2215    1765      NA      NA      NA
5         17    2174      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

I have looked at `diag()` from `base.R`, but I could only get the the data from the main diagonal. Ideally, I'd like to accomplish this using `dplyr` syntax and the pipe.

**Data**

```
structure(list(time = 13:17, A = c(1842, 1898, 2065, 2215, 2174), B = c(1844, 1785, 1865, 1994, 2122), C = c(1689, 1807, 1748, 1811, 1903), D = c(1776, 1617, 1731, 1708, 1765), E = c(1716, 1679, 1590, 1703, 1699)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), vars = "time", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
time = 13:17), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L), vars = "time", drop = TRUE, .Names = "time"), .Names = c("time", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned `dplyr` in your question, you could use `dplyr::lead` to shift the values of columns `B` to `E` by 1, 2 etc. respectively, and then bind the result with columns `time` and `A` from your original data as follows

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_cols(df[, 1:2], map2_df(.x = df[, c(3:ncol(df))],
                             .y = seq_along(df[, 3:ncol(df)]), 
                             .f = ~dplyr::lead(x = .x, n = .y)))
#  A tibble: 5 x 6
#  Groups:   time [5]
#   time     A     B     C     D     E
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    13  1842  1785  1748  1708  1699
#2    14  1898  1865  1811  1765    NA
#3    15  2065  1994  1903    NA    NA
#4    16  2215  2122    NA    NA    NA
#5    17  2174    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Note that your data is grouped by `time` the way you provided it.

Answer (score 5):

Convert the input `DF` except for the first column to a matrix `mat`.  Then since `row(mat) - col(mat)` is constant on diagonals `split` with respect to that creating a list of `ts` class series in `L`.  We used `ts` class since we can later `cbind` them even if they are of different lengths. The diagonals for which `row(mat) - col(mat) >= 0` are the only ones we want so pick off those, `cbind` them together and transpose the result.  Then replace all columns in `DF` except the first with that.  No packages are used.

```
mat <- as.matrix(DF[-1])
L <- lapply(split(mat, row(mat) - col(mat)), ts)
replace(DF, -1, t(do.call("cbind", L[as.numeric(names(L)) >= 0])))
```

giving:

```
  time    A    B    C    D    E
1   13 1842 1785 1748 1708 1699
2   14 1898 1865 1811 1765   NA
3   15 2065 1994 1903   NA   NA
4   16 2215 2122   NA   NA   NA
5   17 2174   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

With some grouping and arranging and `row_number()`, we can do this with `dplyr` and `tidyr`, and we don't lose values.

Looks a bit messy, but here I create a 2-dimensional index where the second dimension is inverted. When these index positions are summed, we get a matching value for diagonal rows.

```
data %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(class, stud, A:E) %>% 
  arrange(row, desc(class)) %>% 
  group_by(row) %>% 
  mutate(time_left = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  transmute(time, class, stud, start_year = time_left + row - 1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time, stud, color = factor(start_year))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace the mirrored upper triangle of "d" with the values from the lower triangle.

```
m <- as.matrix(d[-1])
d[-1] <- NA
d[-1][upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)[ , ncol(m):1]] <- m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)]

#   time    A    B    C    D    E
# 1   13 1842 1785 1748 1708 1699
# 2   14 1898 1865 1811 1765   NA
# 3   15 2065 1994 1903   NA   NA
# 4   16 2215 2122   NA   NA   NA
# 5   17 2174   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: @tifu Just to let you know that I updated my answer with a simpler version.